# Mapping one list of dicts to another in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a clients variable that is defined like this:

```
clients:
  - name: 'acme'
    production: False
    db_pwd: '123'
  - name: 'example'
    production: True
    db_pwd: '456'
```

I need to process this list and come up with another list for users in the mongo database

```
users:
  - database: 'client_acme',
    name: 'client_acme',
    password: '123'
    roles: ['readWrite', 'dbAdmin']
  - database: 'client_example',
    name: 'client_example',
    password: '456'
    roles: ['readWrite', 'dbAdmin']
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this task does the job:

```
- name: "Test1"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    clients:
      - name: 'acme'
        production: False
        db_pwd: '123'
      - name: 'example'
        production: True
        db_pwd: '456'
  tasks:  
    - name: set_fact
      set_fact:
        users: "{{ users | default([]) + [ ({ 'database': newname, 'name': newname, 'password': password, 'roles': ['readWrite', 'dbAdmin'] })] }}"
      loop: "{{ clients }}"
      vars:
        newname: client_{{ item.name }}
        password: "{{ item.db_pwd }}"

    - name: debug users      
      debug:
        var: users
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  users:
  - database: client_acme
    name: client_acme
    password: '123'
    roles:
    - readWrite
    - dbAdmin
  - database: client_example
    name: client_example
    password: '456'
    roles:
    - readWrite
    - dbAdmin
```